# How to get spring MVC controller model key value inside <script> tag

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have looked at duplicate questions but could not relate to my problem.
I am new to Spring MVC.
My controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addNewPost(Employee emp, BindingResult bindingResult, Model   model) {
   empr.save(emp);
   model.addAttribute("Employees", empr.findAll());
   System.out.println(empr.findAll());
   return "display";
}
```

My javascript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data1 = [];
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var emp = ${Employees};// shows Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in this line
```

I want to get reference to Employees key that is sent through `model.addAttribute`. How can this be done?
It is working fine in html though using *thymeleaf*.
(I am using STS 3.8.1 with jquery-1.11.1.min.js and spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf 1.4.0 Release)

```
<p th:each="emp : ${Employees}">
<h4>ID:</h4>
<div th:text="${emp.id}"></div>
<h4>Title:</h4>
<div th:text="${emp.name}"></div>
<h4>Content:</h4>
<div th:text="${emp.address}"></div>
<h4>Salary:</h4>
<div th:text="${emp.salary}"></div>
<div>---------------------------------------------------------</div>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using *thymeleaf* - so you can do this to make it work:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
     /*<![CDATA[*/
     var emp = [[${Employees}]];
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

The `CDATA` part (note that it is *commented* too) tells `thymeleaf` to ignore this section while doing its xml-validation.

And wrapping up the `${Employees}` allows you to write this inside a script tag.